# Do I need multiple PHP sessions for my system?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

**Bit of background:**

We have a buying process that is 4 stages - prices, customer details, payment, order confirmation.

We have multiple products that can be purchased through the same buying process, using the same URLs.

We use PHP sessions to store a lot of the quote data and it is stored until the order is complete.

Many PHP session variables are shared across all of our products such as "grossprice" "product", etc

**The problem:**

If a customer is half way through purchasing something, and then starts browsing the website in another tab, then gets a quote for another product - the current system set up means the shared php session variables can start over writing each other and it screws up the first purchase. For instance the "grossprice" could change at the very last stage because a user has got a quote on something entirely different.

I'm self taught so it's all a learning curve for me - I realise there is a big issue here in the system set up.

At the top of every purchase stage page, I have the following code:

```
session_name("buying_system");  
session_start();
```

Am I right in thinking that I should set the session name, based on the product being purchased?

So something like this:

```
session_name($_GET['product'] . "_buying_system");
```

And then the user could be in the purchase process in two tabs, for different products and the sessions would never clash or overwrite each other?

**POTENTIAL SOLUTION 1:**

```
$_SESSION["quotesarray"] = "";

$quotesArray = array();

$quotesArray["product1"] = array();

$quotesArray['product1']['gross'] = 49.99;
$quotesArray['product1']['sell'] = 45.99;


$quotesArray["product2"] = array();

$quotesArray['product2']['gross'] = 20.99;
$quotesArray['product2']['sell'] = 25.99;

$_SESSION["quotesarray"] = $quotesArray;

$quotesArray["product2"] = "";

$quotesSessionArray = requestSession("quotesarray");

echo $quotesSessionArray['product1']['gross'];
```

Comment: Setting more than one session cookie is not a good solution, frament inside your `$_SESSION` `$_SESSION[$_GET['product']][]`

Comment: @cske expand on this and post as an answer. Great solution

Answer (score 2):

A user will only have one session, so you'll need to handle this use-case differently. A simple way is to allow only one quote at a time; alternatively, you should could create a quotes array and add new quotes to it, using the product id as the array key:

```
$quotes = [
    'product_1' =>  ..., // info about the quote for this product
    'product_2' =>  ..., // info about the quote for this product
];
```

Then store the whole array in the session. When you load a page, you can access the quote based on the product ID.

Comment: I like the idea of this - how does my POTENTIAL SOLUTION 1 look in the original question?

Comment: What do you think of my solution Graham? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Every thing is fine...
your multiple session is working if your use this..

```
session_start();
session_name("buying_system");




session_name("buying_system");  
session_start();
```

Comment: It works of course, but session_name based on _GET is a nightmare

Comment: i think thats not a problem....
the only problem is your session is start after you put values in session..

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is only one session for all the tabs. Session key is saved to cookie and if he does something to the cart then it changes in all of the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are, by definition:

> a dialogue, a conversation or a meeting, between two or more communicating devices, or between a computer and user

When a user opens multiple tabs on a site, the standard solution is to ensure that the initial session is available in all tabs (this is the default behavior). If the user obtained a quote or added items to the shopping cart in the first tab, the same information should be available in the second. If a new quote or cart item is added in the second tab, it should be reflected in the first tab when the user refreshes the page.

Tabs are not new sessions: they are simply tools that a user can use to organize his or her own workflow.

If your site allows users to obtain different quotes for the same item, develop an identifier for each item and attach the quotes to the various identifiers in the user's session. The user will be able to decide which quote in the cart is acceptable and remove the product with the unwanted quote.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to develop a class that represents a Product.

```
class Product { }
```

In your Session, you can hold onto the Product objects for which the user has a Quote:

```
$_SESSION['quotes']
```

You could implement a container class for the Products or store them in an array.  Either way, you will add or remove Products from `$_SESSION['quotes']` based on user action.

When the session is written, the Product objects will be serialized and stored by your Session Handler. When the session is loaded, the Product objects will be unserialized.

In this implementation, if two tabs are open, and the user makes changes in the second tab, when they refresh the first tab, the changes from the second will appear.